# email notification templates changes reverting after the upgrade of Teamcity server

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, devops, teamcity, configuration-management

Is there a way to make file changes in AWS EC2 instance using teamcity job from github repo.

Suppose I've a git repo of email templates, I want to create a teamcity build job to update the email templates in ec2 instance. Is it possible. If so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity is a CI/CD server, it's not intended to perform the configuration management directly. Use a configuration management tool like [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) and run it from a TeamCity build. File changes are a very common task and Ansible has tons of built-in functionality to achieve your goal.